# Rendering static file in django

Tags: django

I already asked question like this but i didn't succeed...

I want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'st_forms/my_script.js' %}"></script>
```

but `my_script.js` is a template. Is there way to do this BUT without include tag?

maybe url tag instead of static or something?
I just want that code in `my_script.js` to be referenced from template not to be included.

### NEW UPDATE

Can this help me(render_to_file): https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/689/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably best not to make templates out of your javascript files.

Instead, provide the data using a REST API with django restframework or tastypie and serve your js as static content.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Here is a good place to start : http://django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart